# Intuition for $m (\omega \times v)$ term in unconstrained rigidbody motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I've been Googling for hours and can't seem to find anything. I'm confused about the intuition behind the formulas for linear dynamics of an unconstrained rigid body. My textbook (Modern Robotics by Lynch and Park) gives the linear dynamics of an unconstrained rigid body in the *inertial* body frame $b$ (instantaneously coincident with the center of mass), with linear velocity $v_b$ and angular velocity $\omega_b$ as

$$f_b = m\dot{v}_b + m(\omega_b \times v_b)$$

I'm very comfortable with $f_b = m\dot{v}_b$, since that's just highschool physics $f = ma$. But I'm confused about the intuition behind the $m(\omega_b \times v_b)$. When I do out a simple example of a 1kg object rotating at $\omega_b = [0, 0, 1 m/s]$, traveling at $v_b = [0, 1 m/s, 0]$, with a force applied of $f_b = [0, 1N, 0]$, I end up with an acceleration of $\dot{v}_b = [-1 m/s^2, 1 m/s^2, 0]$ which doesn't make much sense to me.

So here's my question: How can a push in the positive y-axis direction at the center of mass end up creating an acceleration at a 45 degree angle just because the body is rotating? It's an inertial frame, so I thought we weren't supposed to need fictitious forces, and yet that's the only explanation I can think of.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hint: Lookup derivative of a rotating vector. There you will find that $$ \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} v = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} v + \omega \times v $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\vec\omega\times \vec r_b$ term appear in the rotating (non-inertial) frame.  It is there because the motion of a particle in a rotating frame expressed in the lab contains a "pure" motion on the rotating (non-inertial) frame, plus a term to account for the rotation of the non-inertial frame.

In equations, 
$\vec r'(t)=U(t) \vec r$ where $\vec r'$ is in the lab, $\vec r$ is in the rotating frame, and $U(t)$ is a time-dependent transformation that carries the orientation of rotating set of axes to the fixed ones in the lab.

Taking the time derivative of $\vec r'(t)$ thus involves two pieces by the chain rule, and one can show that 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}U(t)=U U^{-1} \dot{U}(t) 
\end{align}
and that, basically, $U^{-1}\dot{U}$ boils down to an antisymmetric matrix  $\Omega$, so that $\Omega \vec r\equiv \vec\omega \times \vec r$.

Note that a simplified version of this is provided by the Lagrangian description of a free particle 
\begin{align}
    L=\frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2\right)\, ,
\end{align}
as viewed from a rotating coordinate system 
\begin{align}
    x'=x\cos(\theta(t))+y\sin(\theta(t))\, ,\qquad 
    y'=-x\sin(\theta(t))+y\cos(\theta(t))\, ,\qquad 
    z'=z  
\end{align}
where the angle $\theta(t)$ is some function of time.  In terms of these coordinates the Lagrangian takes the form
    \begin{align}
    L=\frac{1}{2}m\left[(\dot{x}')^2 +(\dot{y}')^2 +(\dot{z}')^2
    +2\omega(t)(x' \dot{y}'-y'\dot{x}')+\omega^2(t)(x'^2+y'^2)\right]
\end{align}
    with $\omega(t)=\dot\theta(t)$ is the angular velocity.  The equation of motion for $y(t)$ (for instance) takes the form
\begin{align}
m\ddot{y}'&= -2m\dot{x}'\omega -mx'\dot{\omega }+m\omega^2 y'\, .
\end{align}
These are obtained in the Newtonian framework by including a Coriolis force in the body-frame:
$$
\vec F_C=\hat x (2m\omega \dot{y'})-\hat y(2m\omega \dot{x'})
$$
which is basically $\vec\omega\times \vec r'$ with $\vec\omega=\omega\hat z$.  The centrifugal term in $\omega^2$ is usually neglected unless $\omega$ is large, and the Euler force is in $\dot{\omega}$ and nil if the rotation is uniform.  Of course for the free particle there is no $\dot{v}_b$ term.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was missing something fundamental. I'm pretty sure that the "Modern Robotics" book saying that this is an inertial frame is a typo, and they meant to say non-inertial... Good stuff!

Comment: the notation and nomenclature is really subtle, with body-vectors expressed in the lab frame and body vectors in the body-frame...

Comment: One silly follow up: if the frame is rotating by $\omega$, I would expect the acceleration to keep the velocity pointed in the right direction in the inertial frame to be the reverse vector $- (\omega \times v)$, since you'd want this to the be the inverse of the rotation of the frame to keep everything lined up in an inertial frame. Any intuition about why it's actually opposite what I'd expect?

Comment: you have to be careful here about the signs but depending on how you define things going from lab->body is one sign and from body->lab is another sign.  Since the matrix $\Omega$ is antisymmetric, taking its transpose to go in "the other direction" brings a change in sign.

Comment: For anyone coming here in the future, I figured it out yesterday! The key bit I was missing is that the $v_b$ and $\omega_b$ are relative to the _changing_ inertial body frame. So $\omega_b$ is rotating the body frame, and then $v_b$ is pointing in a new direction in the space frame. This requires some acceleration, since in the space frame the body is tracing out a screw motion.